How to reduce disk space usage during PostgreSQL upgrade
I want to upgrade a large PostgreSQL database using the following command:
docker-compose exec db pg_dumpall -U app | docker-compose exec -T db16 psql -U app

I expected the upgrade to require roughly twice the current database size, but it seems to need significantly more space than anticipated. Currently, there are 161 GB of available space, and the database occupies 123 GB, which should have left sufficient free space. However, I encountered an issue where I ran out of space.
Is there any way to optimize the upgrade process to reduce the amount of additional space required?

Did you try first to make vacuum full?

@RomeoNinov No, but I think this would also only "shrink" the size of the source database (if there's anything left to be cleaned up) but not have any effect on the migration itself, right?

Right, but this will reduce (eventually) the size of the database and can make the process of migration smooth (because of smaller size)
